# Two table join with sequelize (postgres)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two tables, `Teams` and `Votes`. I want to query a ranking ordered by votes count.

This simple raw query does exactly what I want, but I'm not being able represent it in `sequelize`:

```
SELECT 
    id, name, count 
FROM 
    "Teams" teams
LEFT JOIN
  (select team_id, count(*) from "Votes" group by team_id) votes
ON
  votes.team_id = teams.id
ORDER BY
  count DESC
LIMIT 10
;
```

I'm able to get data with:

```
Team.findAll({
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'name'
    ],
    include: [{
      model: Vote
    }],
    limit: 10
  });
```

Which gives me a reference to `.Votes` in each result (there's a `Team.hasMany(Votes)` association). But I just want a `count` grouped by `team_id`.

How can I include the `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` in this code?